# How can I force a language to be used?

Tags: monaco

I use Steam in Finnish and have selected Finnish under Monaco's properties in Steam, but the game still uses English. Is there a command line parameter or something to force the game's language?

Comment: is there a Finnish translation for Monaco, it may still be incomplete...

Comment: @ratchetfreak [Seems pretty finished to me](http://i.3ventic.eu/20131224003537363.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the developers decided not to use the translations after all, and they're not officially part of the game, but you *can still use them* if you have access to Steam Translation Server, or find the translations uploaded somewhere.

### Getting the translations

Go to STS and switch to Pocketwatchgames realm, hit <kbd>Reports</kbd> > <kbd>Export</kbd> and select Monaco file. Then move the downloaded file to `SteamApps\common\Monaco\Tools`.

### Applying the translations to your game

Open your command prompt and change to the same directory. (`cd C:\path\to\Monaco\Tools` or `cd /d F:\path\on\another\drive\to\Monaco\Tools`). Now type in the command prompt: `compileLang.bat [short code] monaco_language.txt` where:

- `[short code]` is your country's short code (e.g. fin for Finnish) and
- `monaco_language.txt` is the file you exported and added to the folder.

---

Now you can simply run the game with the correct language setting.